# Define drawable for CheckedTextView for checked and pressed state in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have current code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_button_selected" />                                   
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_button_pressed" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_button" />
</selector>
```

for my CheckedTextView and it works. But when it's checked and I press on it, it shows default android color for background. How can I overwrite that? I tried

```
<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_button_selected" />
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I think the intended use for each item is to fully qualify each one.  Which would mean having one <item> tag for checked and pressed, one for checked not pressed, one for not checked and pressed and finally one for not checked and not pressed.

Comment: in my case order is important, so I just switched checked and pressed and its working now

Comment: it will use the first match - so if you give all possible combinations, the order shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, order is important. I had to switch checked and pressed and its working now.

Comment: order is everything when you define a state selector resource :) Good job ;)